# Accessing UISegmentedControl @IBOoutlet from another class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol, iboutlet

I have Table View Controller, intended to serve as a settings page, that contains a UISegmentedControl with 3 segments:

```
class SettingsView: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var ButtonSelection: UISegmentedControl!

//Index 0 is default selection (first)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // some code   
}
```

Separately, I have a Navigation View Controller that controls 3 different UIViewControllers with corresponding Storyboard IDs ("first", "second", and "third").

I'm trying to prepare the Navigation View Controller to present the appropriate View Controller based on UISegmentedControl selection. However, I keep getting "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and not sure how to resolve.

This is what I have tried:

```
class NavViewController: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if SettingsView().ButtonSelection.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

       print ("first segment is selected")

       let destinationController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "first")

    else if SettingsView().ButtonSelection.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

       print ("second segment is selected")

       let destinationController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second")

    else if SettingsView().ButtonSelection.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

       print ("third segment is selected")

       let destinationController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "third")
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction, please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems.

Problem 1: A UITableViewController is not set up to host anything **but** a table view. It's content view is locked to be a table view. If you want a table view that's managed by a `UITableViewController` and you want other content in the view controller, you need to make the `UITableViewController` a child of another view controller. The good news is that that is trivially easy using a container view and an embed segue.

Problem 2 is a "don't do that" problem. You should treat a view controller's views as private. Another view controller should not try to look at or change another view controller's segmented control. (It's bad design, and it also can lead to crashes like the one you describe because you can't be sure if the other view controller's views have been loaded yet.) Instead, you should add an integer property "selectedIndex" to the view controller that contains the segmented control, and use that to read/write the selected segment. (In OOP terms, you add a public interface to your view controller's "contract" that exposes the features you want to expose, and then add code that provides that interface.)